# Performance de acordo com a modelagem de controle de caixa

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, desempenho

Estou fazendo um sistema para controle de caixa diário, que permite lançamentos/exclusão de valores. Abaixo está a tabela que armazenará os valores, preenchida com alguns dados para exemplificar. Há mais campos, porém para a dúvida em questão acredito que não seja importante informar.

Tabela 'Movimento':

```
+--------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| id_movimento | data_movimento  | tipo             | valor           |
| 1            | 26/03/2019      | 'R'              | 1000.00         |
| 2            | 27/03/2019      | 'P'              | 200.00          |
| 3            | 28/03/2019      | 'P'              | 100.00          |
+--------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

O 'R' indica recebimento e o 'P', pagamento.

O saldo inicial e o saldo atual ficam armazenados em uma outra tabela, mostrada abaixo.

Tabela 'Conta':

```
+--------------+-----------------+------------------+
| id_conta     | saldo_inicial   | saldo_atual      |
| 1            | 5000.00         | 5700.00          |
+--------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Será feito aproximadamente 10 lançamentos diários, pois o movimento do cliente não é tão grande. Ao mês, serão em média 300 lançamentos. Daqui a 5 anos, terão 18000 lançamentos nesta tabela.

Todo o caixa possui um saldo anterior (formado pela soma de todos os lançamentos dos meses anteriores ao mês atual), um saldo do período (formado apenas pela soma dos lançamentos do período consultado), um saldo acumulado (soma do saldo anterior com os lançamentos do período), e um saldo atual (somatória de tudo até a data atual). O saldo atual da conta é atualizado na tabela 'Conta' a cada lançamento/exclusão de lançamento.

A minha ideia é que, para o saldo anterior, terei que fazer uma consulta SQL com um `SUM` de todos os dados do tipo 'R' da tabela 'Movimento' subtraindo de um `SUM` de todos os dados do tipo 'P' da tabela 'Movimento' desde a data inicial, até o último dia do mês anterior ao mês atual que está sendo consultado.

#### Dúvida

Visto que com alguns anos de uso, haverá bastante linhas na tabela (como por exemplo, em 5 anos, 18 mil lançamentos), qual seria a performance de uma consulta desse tipo? Iria demorar muito para o banco de dados fazer este cálculo? Existe uma forma mais correta de ser feito um controle de caixa?

Comment: 18.000 registos não é nada de extraordinário. Em princípio não terá qualquer problema com a consulta. Se tivesse 18.000.000 sim, aí poderia discutir-se formas de otimizar ao máximo.

Comment: Entendi. Provavelmente um dia terá essa quantidade, mas irá demorar. Obrigado João.

Comment: Se a tabela de SALDO tiver a data do saldo ,  os saldos parciais seriam recalculados a partir desta (uma procedure por exemplo) , mas face aos poucos lançamentos talvez não seja necessário

Comment: Obrigado @Motta. Eu deveria criar uma tabela 'historico_saldos' com a chave estrangeira apontando para o id da conta e com os campos saldo_atual e data? E então sempre que um lançamento for feito/excluído na tabela 'movimento', incluir um novo registro na tabela 'historico_saldos' ?

Comment: Não , algum processo pega o último saldo e calcula o próximo baseado nos lançamentos posteriores. Uso com base o que os erps em geral fazem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta quantidade que um dia pode ter é ridiculamente baixa, e tudo o que demonstrou mesmo em quantidade muito grande não parece causar qualquer problema. Mesmo que erros mais ou menos graves de configuração e modelagem sejam cometidos não deve causar um estrago tão grande, ainda que seja melhor fazer tudo certo para obter o máximo de performance. Mesmo em uma operação de complexidade linear deve fazer as operações citadas em uma fração de segundo em um SSD (em um HDD pode ser que leve alguns segundos, mas só se algo estiver muito errado).

Em geral as pessoas têm expectativas irreais de escala e querem que o sistema esteja apto a lidar com volumes que nunca acontecem ou que esses volumes sejam tão pesados.

Não sei se entendi bem, mas parece que está querendo calcular o saldo todas as vezes? Em geral não é assim que se faz, você faz um lançamento e cria um saldo novo em uma tabela de saldos, assim você tem um histórico de saldos. Mesmo que não queira fazer isto pelo menos o saldo da conta é atualizado todas vezes com o saldo existente e novo lançamento, não precisa pegar outros lançamentos, que é o que foi descrito na pergunta. Então posso não ter entendido a questão do saldo anterior.